# conditional formatting formula for duplicates across 4 columns

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a large spreadsheet with a lot of information in numbers.
10,756 lines up to AX.
I need to find out all line's that have the same information on row F, G, H and I.
when I mean the same information is when all the number in the same line are the same.
for example:

```
F=1 G=2 H=3 I=4.

F=1 G=2 H=3 I=4.
```

and not like this.

```
F=1 G=2 H=3 I=4.

F=1 G=3 H=2 I=4.
```

all of the information in those rows are numbers.
it can be in a conditional formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS($F:F, $F1, $G:G, $G1, $H:H, $H1, $I:I, $I1)>1
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Apply to:

```
A2:AX10756
```

Custom formula:

```
=SUM(--(JOIN(" ",$F2:$I2)=QUERY(TRANSPOSE($F$2:$I$10756),,2^99)))>0
```

- `JOIN` F2:I2 and compare it to joins of the whole  F:I table